# InputSimulator not working for Games in Windows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Does InputSimulator works with Games? 
I have tried with the following code

```
 while (i < 200)
        {
            InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            i++;
        }
```

which works perfectly in some apps like notepad. But failed for NFS Most Wanted Game. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

This is because games most often use DirectX to handle input and do not get their input events from the Window manager. `InputSimulator` most likely just inserts an appropriate message into the message queue.

Comment: Then Whats the best way to send key inputs to NFS?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually built in protection, which most major games have. This is same for most languages, you have to bypass the protection somehow which might be very difficult.